# Responsive text inside of section

Tags: html, css

I have a background image inside of a section and on the image is a paragraph with text. On my screen it looks fine but how do I get the text to be responsive and crop down into multiple lines.
I used position absolute to center everything on my screen because I don't know how else to do it.

```css
    #section-2 {
        background-color: black;
        height: 824px;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        width: auto;

    #pValues {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: white;
        letter-spacing: 0.18em;
        font-size: 4vh;
        font-family: Poppins;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    ul.a {
        list-style-type: circle;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: #ffd400;
        font-family: Boldfont;
    }

    .integrity {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 40%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: #ffd400;
        font-family: Boldfont;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

```html
    <section id="section-2">
      <p id="pValues">ZOO'S VALUES</p>
      <ul class="a">
        <li>Integrity</li>
        <li>Preservation</li>
        <li>Safety</li>
      </ul>
      <p class="integrity">
        Integrity<br>
        <em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor nisi eget orci molestie laoreet et vehicula.</em><br>

        Preservation<br>
        <em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor nisi eget orci molestie laoreet et vehicula.</em><br>

        Safety <br>
        <em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor nisi eget orci molestie laoreet et vehicula.</em>
      </p>  
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your `HTML, CSS` a bit. This will help, I hope.

```css
#section-2 {
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#pValues {
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 0.18em;
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.a {
  list-style-type: circle;
  color: #ffd400;
  font-family: Boldfont;
}

#integrity-div {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.integrity {
  color: #ffd400;
  font-family: Boldfont;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="section-2">
  <p id="pValues">ZOO'S VALUES</p>
  <ul class="a">
    <li>Integrity</li>
    <li>Preservation</li>
    <li>Safety</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="integrity-div">
    <div class="integrity">
      <div>Integrity</div>
      <div>
        <em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor nisi eget orci molestie laoreet et vehicula.</em>
      </div>
      <div>Preservation</div>
      <div>
        <em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor nisi eget orci molestie laoreet et vehicula.</em>
      </div>
      <div>Safety</div>
      <div>
        <em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor nisi eget orci molestie laoreet et vehicula.</em>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much. I am new to web development, could you please break down what you changed so I can do the same in the future?

Comment: A `div` is a complete replacement for most of the tags in `HTML`. I have settled your code in blocks of `divs`. Also applied some better CSS using `flex` which is better than using multiple absolute elements because they can break your web page completely when you try to add more elements. So, always try to use minimal and good CSS.